# Can someone give me a clear explanation on this topic?

Tags: magnetic-fields, differentiation, vector-fields

What is Divergence and Curl of Magnetic field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divergence is a scalar quantity that tells how much a vector field is pointing into or out of a point. For magnetic fields, because there are no magnetic monopoles, the divergence of a magnetic field is zero everywhere ([Gauss' Law for Magnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_magnetism)).

Curl is a vector quantity that tells how a vector field is curving around an axis through a point, with the direction of that axis given by the direction of the curl vector. For magnetic fields, curl is related to the current density and rate of change of the electric field at that point ([Maxwell-Ampère Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law)).